# comparing differences between filehostnames and COUNTING number of differences

Tags: linux

I have edited my question once again to the right question.

## code:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset file_count
for i in *@cfg2html*.html; do
    hostname=${i%%@*}
    echo $hostname
done
file_count=`ls -dq **cfg2html@*.html* | wc -l`
echo $file_count
for i in $hostname; do
    if [ "$hostname[i]" != "$hostname[i++]" ]; 
then $((server_count++));
echo $server_count;
fi
done
```

## end of code

I am able to extract the host name from the file but I want to be able to count number of different hostnames. the counting of number of hostname is assigned to the $server_count variable. for example there are 62 files totally but the number of servers is 13, because there are 13 different names in total for 62 files listed, I want to be able to count the number of servers(13) by fixing my code.  How do I modify my code in right manner based on comparing filenames to get the server count which is 13 in this case. Server names are: ebr-t3, ebr-t4, ebr-t, j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca etc. 13 different server names but in 62 files.

## Output so far below indicating files and number of files:

```
ebr-t3
ebr-t3
ebr-t3
ebr-t3
ebr-t3
ebr-t3
ebr-t4
ebr-t4
ebr-t
ebr-t
ebr-t
ebr-t
ebr-t
ebr-t
ebr-t
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca
ucdmfmddv11
ucdmfmddv11
ucdmfmddv11
ucdmfmddv21
uldmfindv11
uldmfindv11
uldmfindv21
uldmfindv21
uldmsatdv11
uodbfindv11
uodbsatdv11
uodbsatdv11
uodbsatdv11
[root@ebr-t ENV7]# 
[root@ebr-t ENV7]# file_count=`ls -dq **cfg2html@*.html* | wc -l`
[root@ebr-t ENV7]# echo $file_count
62
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an array variable seems like the correct solution:

1. Avoid the multiple `…` expensive executions.
2. Counts all files in one loop.
3. Prints results at the end.
4. The code works the same for any amount of servers.

The code

```
#!/bin/bash

unset file_count_ITS_ENV7_t

for i in ebr-t*@*.html; do
    n=${i%%@*}                             # remove everything after @
    n=${n##ebr-t}                          # remove leading ebr-t
    : $((  file_count_ITS_ENV7_t[n]++))    # increment count of files for server n
done

file_count_ITS_ENV7_total=0
server_count_ITS_ENV7_total=0

for i in "${!file_count_ITS_ENV7_t[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${file_count_ITS_ENV7_t[i]} -ge 1 ]]; then
        echo "Server number $i has ${file_count_ITS_ENV7_t[i]} files"
        : $((file_count_ITS_ENV7_total+=${file_count_ITS_ENV7_t[i]}))
        : $((server_count_ITS_ENV7_total++))
    fi
done

echo "total number of files $file_count_ITS_ENV7_total"
echo "total number of servers $server_count_ITS_ENV7_total"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks Isaac. You saved my day.

Comment: I don't know if you know PHP, but I want to convert the outputted information of this file in PHP format. Let me know if you know the PHP code for converting an output of text file and displaying on a browser.

Comment: There is one problem. Your code is working great BUT since I also have .txt files and .err files with same name as the html file. I want the code to only calculate number of html files.

Comment: There is a problem with your code. If I run it more than once it keeps on incrementing the values. I have made a shorter code taking ideas from your code.>> #!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/cfg2html_outputs/ITS_Shared_Lab/ENV7/
file_count_ITS_ENV7_t=`ls -dq *ebr-t*@*.html* | wc -l`
echo "Number of html files: $file_count_ITS_ENV7_t"
for i in "${!file_count_ITS_ENV7_t[@]}"; do
echo "Number of servers: $i"
done << It is running good except its says "Number of server: 0 Number of Servers: 3". I want it to run in a way it only shows "Number of Servers: 3", how do I do that?

Comment: @raht Please try the edited code, it should keep the count correct on several runs.

Comment: Hey Isaac it is finally working after many runs. Thanks man. Wish I could buy you pack of Cuban cigars for the help.

Comment: He Isaac I have edited my question, because my senior sysadmin wants me to find the number of server hosts based on difference in filenames. could you check my question again and help me out based on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e 'foreach (@ARGV) { my @F=split(/@/,$_); $servers{$F[0]}++ };
         END { printf "%s: %i\n", $_, $servers{$_} for (keys %servers) }' *@*
```

This perl script splits each filename given on the command line by `@` characters into the array `@F`.  It then uses hashed array `%servers` to keep a count of each time it sees the first (zeroth) element of `@F` (i.e. the server-name prefix).

When it has processed all the filenames listed on the command line, it prints a summary (`server: count`) for each prefix.

Example output in a directory with the sample filenames given in your question:

```
$ perl -e 'foreach (@ARGV) { my @F=split(/\@/,$_); $servers{$F[0]}++ };
           END { printf "%s: %i\n", $_, $servers{$_} for (keys %servers)}' *@*
ebr-t: 2
ebr-t2: 1
ebr-t3: 2
ebr-t4: 1
```

Note that hashed arrays (aka associative arrays) are unordered, so the output order will be effectively random (it just happened to come out in the right order for this particular run).  If you want them sorted, you could:

- pipe the output into `sort -V` (GNU sort's natural-sort option - needed because your server names don't have the numerals zero-padded to the same length)

or

- sort the keys in the `perl` one-liner (but you'd need to use the [Natural::Sort](https://metacpan.org/release/Sort-Naturally) CPAN module)

---

BTW, this perl one-liner script could easily be modified to take the list of filenames from stdin instead of (or as well as) the command line.  And could also be easily modified to strip off any leading pathname.  That would make it easy to use with, e.g., `find`.

Comment: Thanks. Although I am using Bash rather than perl.

Comment: that's a perl one-liner, intended to be run in bash (or any other sh interpreter), just as you'd run `awk` or `sed` or `grep` or any other tool in a shell command-line or shell script.   sh is best used to orchestrate other, specialised programs.  Modern shells like bash, ksh, and zsh have gained some impressive features, eliminating the need to call external programs for some common/trivial operations, but they're never going to be as good, or as fast, at processing text as specialised tools like awk or perl.

Comment: I don't know if you know PHP, but I want to convert the outputted information of this file in PHP format. Let me know if you know the PHP code for converting an output of text file and displaying on a browser.

Comment: @raht there's no such thing as "PHP format". PHP is a programming language. Perhaps you meant HTML?

Comment: Yes I mean HTML, but reading the OUTPUT of the shell file and displaying it on HTML

Comment: Hey Cas. I have edited my question once again because my senior sysadmin wanted to me to edited the code bad on the counting number of differences based on names.

Comment: perl -e ...*@cfg2html*html* I've edited your code. I want to be able to find the average. Meaning 62 files divided by 13 servers. How do I do that?

ebr-t: 7
j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca: 5
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca: 10
uldmsatdv11: 1
uldmfindv21: 2
ebr-t3: 6
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca: 9
j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca: 5
uodbsatdv11: 3
ebr-t4: 2
uodbfindv11: 1
uldmfindv11: 2
ucdmfmddv11: 3
ucdmfmddv21: 1
j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca: 5

Comment: Divide the sum of values in the %servers hash by the number of keys in %servers.   BTW if you have a new question, you should post a new question, not change the original one so that the answers no longer match it.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of trolls down voted my question, banning from posting a new question.

Comment: @raht being downvoted does not ban you from posting new questions.  and even if it did, still wouldn't justify editing your question so that it was a new question to evade the ban.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been completely changed. It is almost like a new question.

Acording to the list posted in the question, there are 15 servers (not 13):

```
ebr-t
ebr-t3
ebr-t4
j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca
j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca
ucdmfmddv11
ucdmfmddv21
uldmfindv11
uldmfindv21
uldmsatdv11
uodbfindv11
uodbsatdv11
```

The code to get all the details:

```
file_count=0
server_count=0
shopt -s nullglob
unset server_name s_count
declare -a server_name s_count
s=""
i=-1
for f in *@cfg2html@*@*@.html; do
    file_count=$((file_count+1))
    s1=${f%%@*}
    if [[ $s != $s1 ]]; then
        i=$((i+1))
        s=$s1
        server_name[i]=$s
        server_count=$((server_count+1))
    fi
    s_count[i]=$((${s_count[i]}+1))
    #echo "[$s] ${f%%@*} <${server_count[i]}>"
done
echo "file_count=$file_count"
echo "server_count=$server_count"
declare -p server_name
declare -p s_count
```

On execution (place the script where the server files are):

```
$ cd dir_of_files
$ ./script
file_count=62
server_count=15
declare -a server_name=([0]="ebr-t3" [1]="ebr-t4" [2]="ebr-t" [3]="j-laemgcd.bank-banque-canada.ca" [4]="j-laengine2.bank-banque-canada.ca" [5]="j-lafinrepos2.bank-banque-canada.ca" [6]="j-laimdir1.bank-banque-canada.ca" [7]="j-laimdir2.bank-banque-canada.ca" [8]="ucdmfmddv11" [9]="ucdmfmddv21" [10]="uldmfindv11" [11]="uldmfindv21" [12]="uldmsatdv11" [13]="uodbfindv11" [14]="uodbsatdv11")
declare -a s_count=([0]="6" [1]="2" [2]="7" [3]="9" [4]="5" [5]="5" [6]="10" [7]="5" [8]="3" [9]="1" [10]="2" [11]="2" [12]="1" [13]="1" [14]="3")
```

If the directory is empty, on execution you will get:

```
$ ./script
file_count=0
server_count=0
declare -a server_name
declare -a s_count
```

Comment: @raht maybe an upvote will express the thanks in a clear way.

Comment: Hey Isaac. I upvoted but I don't know why it didn't show up. lol! But hey once again just a minor problem. The code is working absolutely FINE I do have files with @cfg2html@.... in it. BUT let us say my folder is currently empty, I want the server_count to output '0' instead it is outputting '1'. Where can I put an 'if' statement so it outputs zero when my folder is empty, that is my question and what type of if statement should I put?

Comment: @raht See edits.

Comment: Thanks Isaac once more. I upvoted you, but don't why they take time putting it up.

Comment: Hey Isaac Since I am not allowed to post new questions. I though of posting it here. Here is my code which takes information from lines inside a file: for i in `ls *.html`
do
  fhostname=`cat $i | grep "SERVER CONTENT" | cut -d= -f3`
  klevel=`cat $i | grep "KERNEL CONTENT" | cut -d= -f3`
  echo $fhostname $klevel
done

Comment: And it outputs: ebr-t4> 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64>
ebr-t4> 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64>
ebr-t> 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64>
ebr-t> 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64>
ucdmfmddv11> Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC>
ucdmfmddv11> Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC>
ucdmfmddv11> Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC>
ucdmfmddv21> Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC>

Comment: I want to make sure for example: the hostname (ebr-t4>) and kernel (2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64>) doesn't printout twice or more, if two different files have the same hostname and kernel. What if statements can I use?

Comment: Meaning I want it to output like this, despite two or more files have same hostname and kernel: ebr-t4> 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64>  ebr-t> 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64>  ucdmfmddv11> Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC>  ucdmfmddv21> Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC>